# overbrace with flowchart with mathematics

Tags: flow-charts

I am trying to make a flowchart for a controls system.  I'm honestly unsure of the best way to do it.  Some of the things that I would like to include is mathematics and an overbrace so that I can group functional terms to make it easier to understand.  I've distilled it down to the following picture:

[image]
This is a minimum example of what I am looking to do.

Any advice on how to start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a sketch on paper, not a MWE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a decoration called `brace`. You may also be interested in its `calligraphy` variant but here is the basic version for the time being.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
  \node[draw] (dWdt) {$\displaystyle\frac{\partial W}{\partial t}$};
  \node[right=2cm of dWdt,draw] (dpside) {$\displaystyle\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial
  e'}$};
  \path (dpside.south east) ++ (1,-1)   
  node[circle,draw,path picture={
    \draw (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding
    box.north east) 
    (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north
    west);}] (x){};
  \draw[->] (dWdt) -- (dpside);
  \draw (dpside.east) -| coordinate (aux) (x);
  \draw[->] (aux) -- ++ (1,0) node[right]{out $f(x,t)$};
  \draw[<-] (dWdt.west) -- ++ (-0.5,0) |- (x);
  \draw[<-] (x.south) -- ++ (0,-1) node[below]{bias};
  \draw[decoration={brace,raise=1pt,amplitude=4pt},decorate,thick] 
  (dWdt.north west)  -- node[above=1ex]{$W$} (dpside.north east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great work. However, the legend `out f(x,t)` goes near to second rectangle from left to right, in the right upper corner.

Comment: @Cragfelt Thanks a lot! You are right, of course. Corrected.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you.  I appreciate it.  It's actually for the documentation of an analog implementation of the wave function collapse via Schrödinger's equation.  Wonderful coincidence.