# create a picture consisting of math and arrows, boxes - efficient ways

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, arrows, text

What are the ways to create such a picture? As you can see, it consists of math symbols, arrows, boxes, text.
Is it more efficient to load the math symbols in a program like inkscape and do all the drawings in there, or are there packages directly in Tex for that purpose?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/629550/36296 as a starting point. Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529335/36296

Comment: As samcarter suggested, `tikz` is the package you need. it is nearly limitless but difficult to get started with. https://tikz.dev/

Comment: [How to add arrow in equations and matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998) may help. It shows how to annotate math items and text and then add graphical elements.